# Passing selectlist value to a CFC using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, cfc

I am trying to accomplish the following, populate a selectlist from a CFC, then based on that selection populate a form input field from a second CFC call.

I am able to populate the selectlist at this point, but I am unsure how to pass that value in a second AJAX request and return the data from the CFC to my input field.

My Chrome debug console shows this error when my second CFC call happes:

```
500 The VEHICLE_NAME parameter to the getDetail function is required but was not passed in.
```

As of now, I am just populating the input fields with the string "worked" on success. But I would like to pass back the CFC data 'mileage' to the input field instead.

Here are my two ajax calls:

```
<!--- Retieve list of vehicles and mileage --->
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {       
    //populate the vehicle selectlists
    $.ajax({
       url: 'cfcs/mileagedata.cfc?method=getData&returnformat=json',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(response){
           $.each(response.DATA, function(i, row){
            // get value in first column ie "description"
            var vehicle_name = row[0];

            // append new option to list
            $("#vehicle_name").append($('<option/>', { 
                    value: vehicle_name,
                    text : vehicle_name 
            }));

        });
        PopulateOdometers();
       },
       error: function(msg){
           console.log(msg);
       }
    })



});
</script>

<script>
function PopulateOdometers(){
    // Populate the start and stop odometer text boxes when the selectlist ajax completes successfully
    $.ajax({
        url:'cfcs/mileagedata.cfc?method=getDetail&returnformat=json',
        data: { vehicle_name: $("#vehicle_name>option:selected").attr("Value") },
        success: function(response) {
            $("#start_odometer").val( response );
            $("#end_odometer").val( response );
            }
      });
  }
</script>
```

Here is my CFC:

```
<!---Service Vehicle Slect Box --->
<cffunction name="getData" access="remote" returntype="query">

<!--- Function to get data from datasource --->
<!---Get Service Vehicles --->
<cfquery name="data" datasource="#datasource#">
select vehicle_name
from vehicles
where active = '1'
</cfquery>


<!--- Return results --->
<cfreturn data>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getDetail" access="remote" returnType="string">
<cfargument name="vehicle_name" type="any" required="true">

<!--- localize function variables --->
<cfset var dataDetail = "">

<cfquery name="dataDetail" datasource="#datasource#">
    SELECT mileage
    FROM   vehicles
    <!--- adjust cfsqltype if needed --->
    WHERE vehicle_name = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.vehicle_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
</cfquery>

<cfreturn dataDetail.mileage>
</cffunction>
```

Here is my form:

```
<form name="addmileage" id="addmileage" method="post">
         <br />
             <table class="mainTable">
                  <tr>
                    <td><label>Service Vehicle:</label></td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="vehicle_name" id="vehicle_name" onchange="PopulateOdometers();">
                    <option>Select a vehicle</option>
                    </select>                    
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><label>Date:</label></td>
                    <td><input class="calendarInputBox" name="vdate" id="vdate" type="text" required="yes" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <label>Origin:</label></td>
                    <td><input required="yes" name="origin" type="text" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><label>Destination:</label></td>
                    <td><input required="yes" name="destination" type="text" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><label>Start Odometer:</label></td>
                    <td><input id="start_odometer"  name="start_odometer" type="text"  onBlur="stopMaterialCalc();" onFocus="startOdometerCalc();"/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><label>End Odometer:</label></td>
                    <td><input id="end_odometer" name="end_odometer" type="text"  onBlur="stopMaterialCalc();" onFocus="startOdometerCalc();" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><label >Total mileage:</label></td>
                    <td><input id="total_mileage" name="total_mileage" type="text" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><label >Expenses:</label></td>
                    <td><input value="0.00" name="expenses" type="text" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">

                   <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Add Trip"><div class="response" id="addTripMessage"></div>
                    <br />
                   </td>
                  </tr>
            </table>
</form>
```

Comment: you aren't sending a key/value pair as data,  only sending a value. But second request needs to be bound to  an event handler or something. You are making request before first one even completes

Comment: Ok. I sort of get what you're saying. I'm a real novice at java scripting. So should I not load the first request on document.ready?

Comment: I updated my javascript in my question. Is that what you mean chalietfl?

Comment: Ok....so I've got the second AJAX call working to some extent. I can now see that it is grabbing the value of the selectlist and passing to the CFC and the CFC is returning the correct value of the 'mileage' column. I've updated my original post with the modified script. I can verify in the Chrome console under the response section that the data is being sent back. But it doesn't seem to be firing my second AJAX call when I change my selection, only on document.ready(). How can that be changed?

Comment: you would need to call it from within an event handler like `change()`

Comment: ah....It's starting to click now. I added onchange="PopulateOdometers();" to my selectlist and that does the trick. Last piece to the puzzle, how can I populate the #start_odometer and #end_odometer text boxes with the response from the CFC instead of the string "worked"? I tried '#mileage#' but that fails.

Comment: best would be to return JSOn from a struct so you can assign each property to the proper input value

Comment: I can't just insert the string value that is returned?

Comment: sure, if it is the same value for both

Comment: Yes it is the same value for both fields. Would the syntax be  something like: $("#start_odometer").val( #dataDetail.mileage# );

Comment: no, there is no CF code in browser , you want the `response` of ajax  success  `$("#start_odometer").val( response )`